# Despise the rich

Tags: vocabulary

I remember seeing a word that means the movement or the people that resent/despise the rich and wealthy. I've tried googling but not one word came even close. Anyone?

Thanks

Comment: Well, during the October Revolution, the *bolsheviks* overthrew the *bourgeoisie* and the peasants overthrew the *kulaks*, expropriating and redistributing their wealth among the populace. In Marxist theory, the working class people who are eternally pitted against the historical owners of the means of production  are known as the *proletariat*, derived from its origins in Roman law. But ... not all these words are English. Are you thinking of the "99%ers" (*ninety-nine-percenters*), maybe?

Comment: Are you talking about recently? If so, there was the "Occupy" movment protesting against social and economic inequality. They are most famous for their Occupy Wall Street protest.

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid what I was looking isn't any of these. I remember looking it up on a dictionary and it meant the movement/people that despise the rich. Shame that it escaped me!

Comment: Do you know what time period the movement belonged (or belongs) to?

Comment: @Grizzled As far as I remember, it just meant the general movement/people/tendency/compulsion/propensity/etc. toward despising/resenting/etc. the wealthy. Sorry for not being as clear as I'd like.

Comment: @Kate no, you were completely clear.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a *single* word for you, but the phrases *class envy*, *class warfare*, *class conflict*, and/or *class struggle* define the tension between the rich and the poor.  (See [Class Conflict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_conflict) at Wikipedia for details.)

Answer (score -4):

Perhaps you are looking for the word plutophobia.

Comment: Can you link a source? Most websites I can find using this term say it is used for a psychological phobia, that of fearing wealth or money.