# Another word for "expropriate", or an antonym for "privatize"

Tags: single-word-requests

While writing [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251130/despise-the-rich%23comment546806_251130) on the ["*Despise the rich*" question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/251130/55623):

> Well, during the October Revolution, the bolsheviks overthrew the bourgeoisie and the peasants overthrew the kulaks, **expropriating** and redistributing their wealth among the populace. In Marxist theory, the working class people who are eternally pitted against the historical owners of the means of production are known as the proletariat, derived from its origins in Roman law.

I ended up using the verb *expropriate*, but that wasn't the one I was reaching for. I have a recollection that there's another, more specific, and morphologically more obvious synonym (perhaps derived from the root *public*).

What are other words which describe the act of the government (often forcibly) taking ownership of private property, so that the property is under the collective ownership of the public?

> After the Revolution, the new communist Cuban government *___ized* many sugar mills, angering foreign interests who had invested in their creation.

<sub>**Note**: the word is **not** "[*eminent domain*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminent_domain)", which describes a *policy* which permits the *act* I'm describing, nor is it *expropriate* nor *appropriate*, which are often used in contemporary discussions of governments making use of eminent domain.</sub>

Comment: Maybe [governmentalize](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/governmentalize) is even more specific.

Comment: @ermanen Wow, I didn't even know that was a word. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: One of slogans during Soviet expropriation was "Rob the robbed", a Lenin's translation of "expropriation der expropriateure"... so i think the term `robbery` has a right to be used here :)

Comment: @EugenePetrov: Isn't that "rob the robbers"?

Comment: @MSalters the sense is similar, but literally translated it was 'things that was robbed' ("грабь награбленное")

Comment: @EugenePetrov: Ah, so it's more "steal what was stolen". "the robbed" is easily interpreted as "the victims of theft"

Comment: @MSalters hmm, really it seems 'robbed' is usually used to refer a victim, while 'stolen' is taken when nobody saw that, with no force involved, interesting how to differ it from 'taken by force'.

Comment: If you have free time, I would appreciate your comment to my answer and to Janus Bahs Jacquet's comment. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336067/he-is-a-little-more-sophisticated-man-complete-sentence If my answer doesn't make sense, I don't see any reason to keep it.

Comment: @Rathony I upvoted your answer because it made sense to me. Seemed credible. Is it deleted now? I'll open the site in a browser if that's he case.

Comment: @DanBron I will undelete it for now. I think Janus' comments make much sense. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @Rathony Ok, I'll be back at my desk in an hour or so. I'll take a look then. I have 10K+, so if you prefer to leave it deleted, I'll still be able to read it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the term you are looking for is *to [nationalize](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nationalize):*

> - to bring under the ownership or control of a nation, as industries and land.
>
>   - *a movement to nationalize the oil industry*.

(dictionary.reference.com)

Comment: I thought "nationalize" was mainly used regarding foreign-owned assets, and the government control was incidental. Of course, it applies reasonably well to OP's case regardless.

Answer (score 9):

The word *nationalize* means bring under control of a nation, however, you might also consider *collectivize*, particularly if you are talking about the peasants in the former Soviet Union, where the agricultural policy was called [collectivization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectivization_in_the_Soviet_Union).

Comment: Yes, nationalize was the word I was looking for, but I'm very happy to learn the USSR-specific term *collectivization*, which I've never encountered before (or had, and simply forgot). +1.

Answer (score 3):

"Nationalizing" is not incorrect, but given Marxist ideology, probably would not have been used by the actors in question.

"Collectivizing" is probably what they would have used at the time.

"Seizing" would also work, particularly if you wanted to put a negative spin on things, however, it probably lacks the "for the good of the public" intention.

Comment: Thanks, after your edit clarifying the missing connotation of *seizing*, I think that word can stand as an answer. I would council you to either credit the other posters who previously suggested *nationalizing* and *collectivizing*, respectively, or remove those words from your answer (as it stands, you answer has the appearance of stepping on their toes). I'd also suggest you move *seizing* to the top of your answer, as it is the novel part of your response.

Comment: "for the good of the public" isn't relevant in this context. The rationale was "for the good of the (communist) Party". The reason why "for the good of the public" doesn't make sense is that in Marxist-Leninist ideology, "the public" implies a single class whereas this collectivization was part of class warfare.

Answer (score 1):

A specific verb would be ***govermentalize***.

> to bring under governmental, or national, control [*[Collins]*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/governmentalize)

Additionally, the following verbs are mentioned in the book *Privatization: The Key to Better Government* by Emanuel S. Savas:

- municipalize
- statify
- deprivatize

Comment: Heh, *deprivatize* (~ *deprive*, *deprivations*). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised nobody suggested this: **stealing**

Comment: In context, this is a correct word. Under Eminent Domain, the government may forcefully acquire certain goods or lands, but only at a fair price. The Communist governments mentioned in the question had no intent of paying at all, let alone a fair price. In fact, as a former Russian land owner, you'd be lucky to survive Stalin. It literally was _armed robbery_.

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of a citizen of a former communist country:

- collectivization was used mainly in the context of agriculture and even then it was (I think) meant as a one-time, already completed act (~1950 thing in our country)
- nationalization was used in the general context - you could have nationalized industry, factories, services, farms ... We were even celebrating Day of Nationalization :).